# Perform bitwise OR without sign extension in Java

Tags: java, unsigned

In Java, I have the following code:

```
    byte lo = 0x88;
    byte hi = 0x0;
    short x = 0;
    x |= lo;
    x |= (short) ((short) hi << 8); // FIXME double cast ??
    return x;
```

After the first operation, the value in the short is `0xff88`. I understand this is because Java does not support unsigned numbers.

How can I force it to ignore the sign? I'm not using this data directly in Java code so it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: `byte lo = 0x88;` does not compile and its value is outside the range of numbers represented by a `byte`.

Comment: @AR.3 I would like to know how to avoid the sign.

Comment: Your current code doesn't compile. Could you provide a complete, working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign is appearing when the byte is converted to an int prior to performing the bitwise operation.  The conversion must sign extend the `byte` value because `byte` is a signed type in Java.  The conversion must occur because bitwise operations are either operations on `int` values or `long` values.

There are two solutions:

1. Mask the top bits, either after the conversion to an `int`, or after performing the bitwise OR; e.g.

   ```
   x |= (lo & 0xff);
   x |= (hi & 0xff) << 8;
   ```

   (It turns out that the masking is unnecessary for `hi` ... because of what you do later.  However, the chances are that the JIT compiler will optimize away any unnecessary masking instructions.  And if it doesn't, the overhead is so small that it it is unlikely to matter.)
2. Use `Byte.toUnsignedInt(byte)` to convert the `byte` to an `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. This solved the problem.